# Separate bibliographies at the end of the document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a document where each chapter acts as a refsection and resets the references counter. I know I can print the individual bibliographies at the end of each chapter, but I'd like to have them all at the end of the document instead. For example if I have three chapters A,B,C, I'd like the document to look like:

**Chapter A**

...

**Chapter B**

...

**Chapter C**

...

**Bibliography**

Chapter A

[1]

[2]

...

Chapter B

[1]

[2]

...

Chapter C

[1]

[2]

...

My LaTeX document looks something like this

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mydocument.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
... some text here and some \cite{} commands...
\chapter{B}
... some text here and some \cite{} commands...
\chapter{C}
... some text here and some \cite{} commands...

% This will only produce the bibliography for chapter C
% What I'd like to have here is something that will produce
% Bibliography
% Chapter A
% ...
% Chapter B
% ...
% Chapter B
% ...
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` has you covered. You can use:

```
\bibbysection
```

The documentation describes it as:

> This command automatically loops over all reference sections. This is
>   equivalent to giving one `\printbibliography` command for every section
>   but has the additional benefit of automatically skipping sections
>   without references.

By what you described, it is probable that you also want option `defernumbers=true`, but it is hard to say more in the absence of compilable code.

To get specific titles per bibliography's chapter, as requested in the comments, you'll have to be verbose:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}

\chapter{B}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\chapter{C}

\cite{massa}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[section=1,heading=subbibliography,title={References for chapter A}]
\printbibliography[section=2,heading=subbibliography,title={References for chapter B}]
\printbibliography[section=3,heading=subbibliography,title={References for chapter C}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more automated and shorter alternative to the same purpose would be (courtesy of @moewe):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibheading{bibbysubsect}{\section*{References for Chapter \ref{blx:refsection\therefsection}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\label{blx:refsection\therefsection}

\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}

\chapter{B}
\label{blx:refsection\therefsection}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\chapter{C}
\label{blx:refsection\therefsection}

\cite{massa}

\printbibheading
\bibbysection[heading=bibbysubsect]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. I feel that I am really close. The final thing is that `\bibbysection` labels all section as "References", so I get a string of References instead of Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Chapter 3. Is there an option to tell it to use the chapter names or numbers instead? I tried the `heading` option but no luck.

Comment: @Jenny Take a look a the edit. I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: You could try something like `\defbibheading{bibbysubsect}{\section*{References for Chapter \ref{blx:refsection\therefsection}}}` with `\bibbysection[heading=bibbysubsect]` where you would have to manually add `\label{blx:refsection\therefsection}` after each `\chapter`.

Comment: @moewe You're right as usual! Rolled back. Thanks again.